# Terminology for equation solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, systems-of-equations

A question about terminology:

I have a simple trigonometric equation in one unknown $\theta$,
$$A \cdot \cot(\theta) + B = 0.$$

I want to say that "this equation has either no solution, infinitely many solutions, or unique solution, depending on the values of the parameters $A$ and $B$".

How can this be worded more concisely? Would it be OK to write "the behavior of the equation depends on the values of the parameters $A$ and $B$"? Any better idea?

Comment: Depends on the audience

Comment: I'd go for "whether the equation is solvable for $\theta$ depends on the values of $A$, $B$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The cardinality of the solution set depends on the parameters".

Comment: I thought about using that formula. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: @Matteo Honestly I meant it as a kind of joke, it sounds way too pedantic (at least for my taste). Maybe replacing "cardinality" with "structure" or "number of solutions".